# Is it possible to access a SQLite database file outside of an executable JAR?

Tags: sqlite, jdbc, executable-jar

I have an application that I deploy as an executable JAR file. Originally, this JAR file would communicate with a MySQL database but recently I have decided I want to go with SQLite instead. However, while testing I found that I could not access my SQLite database file when running my application from the JAR file.

I'm using the JDBC driver from the following website: http://zentus.com/sqlitejdbc/index.html

Is there a workaround I have to do?

The driver works great while testing in my Eclipse environment, but doesn't seem to work standalone in a JAR file. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, here is such term as "working directory". It is the directory from where your application is started. So, every "relative" path in your application is usually relative to this "working directory".

Now let's return to your problem. When you set the path to a file you can make it either relative, absolute or relative to the JAR inner directory root, depending how you do create the file and set the path.

So, just recheck how paths are set in your application and try to use the relative one, running you application from the appropriate directory.

Comment: I tried it with a hard-coded path to the file on my C:\ drive just for testing. The following did not work: Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC"); Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:C:\\test.db");

I also tried to use Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:test.db"); but of course that didn't work because the working directory is probably inside the JAR file right? Ideally, I want my .db file to live right beside the JAR file.

Can I do?: Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:..\\test.db");

Comment: No, the working directory is not inside the JAR. Try the `file://C:/some/dir` style of specifying the path to your DB.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but it turns out that if I use the Export feature of Eclipse then it all works out fine. When I was using my own command string using the jar command then it wasn't working properly. Strange, but go Eclipse for being AWESOME!