# Why can't I insert or update a SQLite database from an executable JAR file?

Tags: java, sqlite, insert, executable-jar

I have an application that I deploy as an executable JAR file. Originally, this JAR file would communicate with a MySQL database but recently I have decided I want to go with SQLite instead. However, while testing I found that I can't insert into or update the database when running my application from the JAR file.

I'm using the JDBC driver from the following website: http://zentus.com/sqlitejdbc/index.html

Is there a workaround I have to do?

The driver works great while testing in my Eclipse environment, but doesn't seem to work standalone in a JAR file. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Below is a code snippet of what I'm doing:

```
public abstract class AbstractDataUpdator implements DataUpdator{

    protected String description;
    public String[] fieldsToSelect;
    protected String queryString;
    protected String updateString;
    protected String tableName;
    protected String whereStatement;
    protected String groupByStatement;
    protected String orderByStatement;
    protected ResultSet queryResultSet;
    protected Connection connection;
    protected PreparedStatement preparedStatement;
    protected Statement statement;
    protected Database db;
    protected String uri, username, password;
    protected int dbIndex = 0;
    protected static int numInstances = 0;
    protected String countQueryString;
    protected int maxLookupNo = 0;
    protected boolean preparedStatementAlreadyCreated = false;

    AbstractDataUpdator(String description ){
        this.description = description;
        //this.fieldsToSelect = fieldsToSelect;
        //this.tableName = tableName;
        //setupDatabase(databaseName, serverName);

        numInstances++;

    }

    public void setupDatabase(String databaseName, String serverName) {
        // MySQL
        //uri = "jdbc:mysql://"+serverName+"/"+databaseName;

        // SQLite
        uri = "jdbc:sqlite:myfirst_sqlite_db";

        // If there is already a database object in the pool with this information we want to use that object
        // instead of creating another one.
        dbIndex = DatabasePool.getInstance().getIndexOfDatabaseWithThisInfo(uri, username, password);
        if( dbIndex == -1 ){
            db = new Database( uri, username, password );

        }else{
            db = DatabasePool.getInstance().getDatabaseAt(dbIndex);
        }

        try {
            connection = db.getConnection().getConnection();
            connection.setAutoCommit(true);
            statement = connection.createStatement();

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println("SQL error occured in setupDatabase() --> "+e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public String executeUpdate(){

        //System.out.println(updateString);

        try {

            if( updateString != null){
                statement.executeUpdate( updateString );
                return null;
            }
            return "update string is null";

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println("SQL error occured in executeUpdate()"+e.getMessage());
            return e.getMessage();

        }catch (OutOfMemoryError e){
            System.out.println("out of memory due to execute update function!!!!");
            return e.getMessage();

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have write permission in the folder you create the sqlite database?

Comment: Yeah, it's on my desktop of a vm. No permissions are set on the file.

Comment: What means **it does not work**? Do you get Exceptions? Does simple nothing happen?  (Use `e.printStackTrace()` instead of `e.getMessage()`, this gives usually more details.)

Comment: I don't believe any error message is showing, just that the data isn't being saved to the database.

Comment: OK. The 'extract the DB' is apparently not the problem.  How are you running the Jar?  Does it have a manifest that specifies the main class so you can double click it to launch it?  Is it launched using JWS?  As an applet?  From the command line or a .bat file or equivalent?  (What I'm trying to find is - could there be a security manager in place?)

Comment: I actually found that it's not working from Eclipse either. For some reason it just won't persist the data I'm trying to store into the SQLite database.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to access a SQLite database file outside of an executable JAR?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5461286/is-it-possible-to-access-a-sqlite-database-file-outside-of-an-executable-jar)

Answer (score 1):

> However, while testing I found that I can't insert into or update the database when running my application from the JAR file.

No.  Entries within Jars on the application's run-time class-path cannot be updated.  The Jars are generally locked.

As a result of that, a read only DB can be deployed in a Jar.  For update, the DB would first need to be expanded out to the file-system.

Comment: The database lives outside of the executable jar. I can read from the database file but can't write to it. It appears that a journal file is created (maybe a pending transaction is chillin' in there?).